# How can I transpose each vectors of a list assign a unique number to them, and bind them in r?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, type-conversion

I have following list and would like to create a data.frame with each of the lists (there are many) combined. Here an example:

```
v11 <- c("was_on_the_moon", "safe", "best", "super")
v22 <- c("no", "yes", "three", "four")
dat1 <- data.frame(cbind(v11, v22))
v11 <- c("was_on_the_moon", "safe", "best", "super")
v22 <- c("no", "yes", "three", "four")
dat2 <- data.frame(cbind(v11, v22))
list_first <- list(dat1, dat2)
```

The result should be as follows:

```
  was_on_the_moon safe   best super 
1 yes              yes  three  four
2 no              sure  check  four
```

Comment: I don't see `check` anywhere in the example. You have a list where the column heading are variables, and want to pivot so they are columns, and then bind? Typically with a list of data sets you can start with `do.call(rbind, my_list)` but you would need them to be consistent with column names.

Comment: Your expected output is not consistent with the example data you provided. Please revise it or explain more.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
map(list_first, ~ setNames(., c("var", "val"))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
  spread(var, val)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a <- unlist(myfiles, recursive = FALSE)
names <- a$V1
t(sapply(myfiles, function(x) setNames(x$V11, names)[match(names, x$V22)]))
```